# What is the correct way to use a .join() function?

Tags: python, function, join

So I am new to coding and as part of my course I am making a hangman game. When I run the program, it says "['*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*']
Input : ". I want to make it so that the apostrophes and commas are not printed. I feel like the .join() function would be the best way to do this, but as I am still learning, I am not sure how and/or where to place the function. Please bear with me! Thank you!!

```
original=list(word)
temp=list(word)
guess=[] #null list
lettersguessed=[]
trial=int(0) #for keeping track of guessess
userinput=''
counter=int(0) #keeping track of position of element in list (if found)
letterlist=['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']


for i in range(len(original)): #creating the '_ _**....' list
    if (original[i]==' '):
        guess.append(" ") #(whitespace) for vowels
    else:
        guess.append("_") #_ for all other alphabets
```

Comment: You need to have a specific problem. What isn't working? Also, example output of what you want and what you currently get is helpful.

Comment: ok. I'm new to coding and stack overflow so I wasnt sure how to format and what the responders would want. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i got what you want.
i just moved the if statement of the used letters to the top of your while, and instead of appending to the lettersguessed the guess variable, i appended the userinput variable.

```
print "WELCOME TO HANGMAN!"

print '                                            '

print '------------------------------------------'

print '                                            '

import random #for random.choice
dictionary=['CODING', 'GENEPEEKS', 'PYTHON', 'FREE TOM BRADY', 'BOSTON']
word=random.choice(dictionary)
original=list(word)
temp=list(word)
guess=[] #null list
lettersguessed=[]
trial=int(0) #for keeping track of guessess
userinput=''
counter=int(0) #keeping track of position of element in list (if found)


for i in range(len(original)): #creating the '_ _**....' list
    if (original[i]==' '):
        guess.append(" ") #(whitespace) for vowels
    else:
        guess.append("_") #_ for all other alphabets

print guess

while trial<15:
    userinput=str.upper(raw_input('Input : '))

    if userinput in lettersguessed:  # test presence
        print "This letter has been used already!"
        continue
    else:
        lettersguessed.append(userinput) # remember as used

    if len(userinput)>1: #checking for multiple characters
        print 'Error : Input only a single character'
        trial -= 1
        continue

    if userinput in original:
        while userinput in temp: #loop for checking redundant characters
            counter=temp.index(userinput)
            guess[counter]=userinput
            temp.remove(userinput)
            temp.insert(counter,'_')

        counter=0

        for i in range(0,len(temp)): #checking for final guess match with original
            if temp[i]=='_':
                counter+=1



        if counter==len(original): #if guess matches original
            print 'Correct\t', guess
            print 'You Win !'
            trial=10
            break

        print 'Correct\t' , guess , '\tTrials left: ', (9-trial)

    else:
        trial+=1
        print 'Incorrect', '\tTrials left: ', (9-trial)
else:
    print 'You Lose !'
    print 'Correct answer was\t', original
```

Comment: Thanks so much! this really helped! one more question. how would i use the .join() function so that instead of printing ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_'] it prints _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ?

Comment: @Eli.r , you can use it like this. var = "".join("_ "*8), so the variable var is _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _.  it writes 8 underscore and after each one one space.

Answer (score 0):

add at the begining:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
options = set(ascii_uppercase)
```

and after the input-one-chart-checking add checking for permitted letter:

```
    if userinput not in options:
        print 'Error: you already chose -', userinput
        continue
    else:
        options.remove(userinput)
```